# Show heading on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, compass

I would like to display a small cone next to the current position to show heading.
I also would like to be able to customize it to have a dragraded effect.

[image: Exemple of result:]

How could I get this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As you might know, you can use `MKUserTrackingMode ` to show heading.

Comment: Yes I know I to get the needed information. What I don't know is how to draw it on screen. This specific shape.